# How to change login id for stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, login, openid

Open ID is really a nice feature. But if i wish to change my email id there, Stack Overflow i guess considers it as a prime key and won't allow to change.

For instance i had used my company's mail id while signing up using google OpenId but now i wish to switch the account over to my personal email id. So that i can login using my personal email id.

Is there any way we can do so?